# JQuery Isotope plugin not allowing custom css animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am working on a project and using the Isotope library for jquery. Prior to incorporating Isotope, I created a basic css class that contained some code to perform a css transform to rotate an element. I used jquery to apply that class onclick and fire the transform. Now when I attempt to apply that class to trigger the transform on an element within the isotope container, the transform will not apply. I am able to add/remove other classes but transform classes have no effect. I can tell that something within isotope is not allowing the transform to fire and I am hoping someone might be able to tell me A)what it might be and B)if/how I might turn it off (if its an option)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it's blocking the firing of the event? It could be that it inserts a class directly on the element, which would take precedence over your stylesheet, and that class may cancel out your animation.  Look at the DOM and the styles for the element to see if your css is crossed out.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. That was indeed the problem. I was looking at the elements and missing the fact it was inserting the style directives inline. I was able to fix this by passing in the directive "transformsEnabled: false" when I initialized Isotope. This forces it to use js for its built in animations and allowed my css animations to work properly.

Comment: that's a neat directive. I learned something too!